# High CPU usage on Raspberry PI while reading network stream with .NET

Tags: .net, linux, raspberry-pi4

I want to read a networkstream in .NET 8.0 (ARM64 Console Application) on a Raspberry PI (Model 4 - 8GB Ram).
The stream comes from an IpCam and has approximately 800 kB/s.
On my windows machine it is running fine with a CPU usage of about 0-2%.

When I start it on the Raspberry Pi, it has a CPU usage up to 40%.

[image]

I know, that the performance of a Raspberry Pi is not that good. But is it realistic, that the CPU usage is so high, on just reading some bytes from a network stream?

Here is my code:

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool isRunning = true;

        Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
        {
            isRunning = false;
            e.Cancel = true;
        };

        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int totalBytes = 0;
        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        SetDigestAuthenticationMode(httpClientHandler, new Uri(uri), userName, password);
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
            HttpResponseMessage headerResponse = await client.GetAsync("", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            using (Stream stream = await headerResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                do
                {
                    int bufferLength = 4000;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
                    int byteReads = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    totalBytes += byteReads;
                    Console.WriteLine(byteReads);
                }
                while (isRunning);
            }
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"{(totalBytes / stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds) / 1000} kB/s");
    }

    private static void SetDigestAuthenticationMode(HttpClientHandler handler, Uri uri, string userName, string password)
    {
        NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache
        {
            { uri, "Digest", networkCredential }
        };

        handler.Credentials = credentialCache;
        handler.PreAuthenticate = true;
    }
```

The Stopwatch was just for debugging issues. First I tried it without it.
My Question is, is there something wrong in my code, or is the bad performance expected?